# Can't set cookie in server action Next js 13.4

Tags: cookies, next.js

Im trying to set a cookie in actions and it giving me an error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler, but I have them in the server action.

path is app/actions.ts

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";


export async function getCookie() {
    "use server";
    const cookieStore = cookies();

    const calenderId = cookieStore.get("calenderId")?.value;

    return Promise.resolve(calenderId);
}

export async function setCookie(id: string) {
    "use server";
    
    cookies().set("calenderId", id);
}
```

I tried to do it in the server component, but that didn't work either.

Here is a part where I call setCookies() it's in app/page.tsx and it's server component

```
if (!calenderId) {
    calender = await prisma.calendar.create({ data: {} });
    await setCookie(calender.id);
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround that worked for me was to call the server function inside `useEffect` as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCookie("newId").then();
}, []);
```

This is bug in nextjs, you can follow this bug here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/51875

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call server actions like ordinary functions, at least not in server components. From the docs:

> You can invoke Server Actions using the following methods:

> Using action: React's action prop allows invoking a Server Action on a  element.

> Using formAction: React's formAction prop allows handling , , and  elements in a .

> Custom Invocation with startTransition: Invoke Server Actions without using action or formAction by using startTransition. This method disables Progressive Enhancement.